# Show image in gallery after saving it

Tags: react-native

```
const saveToGallery = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
      );

      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log("write Permisisons granted");
        const sourcePath = `${RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath}/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/${params.item}`; // Replace with the actual file path
        const filename = sourcePath.split("/").pop(); // Extract the filename from the source path
        await RNFS.mkdir(RNFS.PicturesDirectoryPath + "/WhatsAppStatusSaver");
        const destPath =
          RNFS.PicturesDirectoryPath + "/WhatsAppStatusSaver/" + filename; // Destination path in the gallery directory

        // Check if the file already exists in the gallery
        const fileExists = await RNFS.exists(destPath);
        if (fileExists) {
          console.log("File already exists in the gallery:", destPath);
          return;
        }
        

        // Move the file to the gallery directory

        await RNFS.copyFile(sourcePath, destPath);
        const asset = await ML.createAssetAsync(`file://${destPath}`);
        console.log(`file://${destPath}`);
        await ML.saveToLibraryAsync(asset);
        ToastAndroid.show(
          "File saved to gallery successfully!",
          ToastAndroid.SHORT
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      ToastAndroid.show("Error saving file to gallery", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
      console.log("Error saving file to gallery:", error);
    }
  };
```

im using the medialibrary but it saves the file again in dcim when i move the file to my folder. i want to show the image in gallery after user saves it as this causes duplication .the gallery doesnt show the image or video when i save it in my app .Ps im using bare workflow in react native